# Exception when calling gRPC server from .Net Framework client

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a gRPC server implemented in .Net Core that I would like to contact with a console app running in .Net Framework.

Here is a working repo of the issue:

https://github.com/q-bertsuit/grpc-framework-core-issue

The following .Net Core Client works fine:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        var input = new MyModel();

        var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001");
        var client = new Test.TestClient(channel);

        var reply = await client.SetTestAsync(input);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The following .Net Framework client throws an exception:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Channel channel = new Channel("https://localhost:5001", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
        
        var    client = new Test.TestClient(channel);

        MyModel request = new MyModel();

        var reply = client.SetTest(request);

        channel.ShutdownAsync().Wait();


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I get the following exception when sending the request:

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="DNS
> resolution failed for service: https://localhost:5001",
> DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException:
> {"created":"@1600333768.055000000","description":"Resolver transient
> failure","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x86\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolving_lb_policy.cc","file_line":215,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1600333768.055000000","description":"DNS
> resolution failed for service:
> https://localhost:5001","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x86\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\c_ares\dns_resolver_ares.cc","file_line":378,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1600333768.055000000","description":"C-ares
> status is not ARES_SUCCESS qtype=A name=https://localhost:5001
> is_balancer=0: Could not contact DNS
> servers","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x86\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\c_ares\grpc_ares_wrapper.cc","file_line":287,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1600333768.055000000","description":"C-ares
> status is not ARES_SUCCESS qtype=AAAA name=https://localhost:5001
> is_balancer=0: Could not contact DNS
> servers","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x86\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\c_ares\grpc_ares_wrapper.cc","file_line":287}]}]}]}")'

On the server I get this error:

> dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[17]
> Connection id "0HM2QU64LCR9J" bad request data: "Unrecognized HTTP version: 'HTTP/2.0'"
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException:
> Unrecognized HTTP version: 'HTTP/2.0'    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.RejectUnknownVersion(Byte* version, Int32 length)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler
> handler, Byte* data, Int32 length)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler handler, ReadOnlySequence`1& buffer, SequencePosition& consumed,
> SequencePosition& examined)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.IHttpParser<TRequestHandler>.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler handler, ReadOnlySequence`1& buffer, SequencePosition& consumed,
> SequencePosition& examined)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.TakeStartLine(ReadOnlySequence`1& buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.ParseRequest(ReadOnlySequence`1&
> buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.TryParseRequest(ReadResult
> result, Boolean& endConnection)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
> application) dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[10]
> Connection id "0HM2QU64LCR9J" disconnecting. dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[2]
> Connection id "0HM2QU64LCR9J" stopped. dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets[6]
> Connection id "0HM2QU64LCR9J" received FIN. dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets[7]
> Connection id "0HM2QU64LCR9J" sending FIN because: "The Socket transport's send loop completed gracefully."

Added Http/2 support in Kestrel as suggested, but still got an error:

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Unknown", Detail="Received
> http2 header with status: 307",
> DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException:
> {"created":"@1600342649.633000000","description":"Received http2
> :status header with non-200 OK
> status","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x86\src\core\ext\filters\http\client\http_client_filter.cc","file_line":130,"grpc_message":"Received
> http2 header with status: 307","grpc_status":2,"value":"307"}")'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by following [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/61121433/1235291)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the constructor parameter for `Channel` expects the value to be in URI format; your best bet is probably:

```cs
Channel channel = new Channel("localhost", 5001, ChannelCredentials.Insecure)
```

although it *may* also work as:

```cs
Channel channel = new Channel("localhost:5001", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! It didn't solve the issue though, unfortunatly. Please see the queastion for the additional infor I added

Comment: @Q-bertsuit with the edit, it looks like you simply haven't told Kestrel to use http/2, which is required - kinda like here: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/blob/main/examples/pb-net-grpc/Server_CS/Program.cs#L20

Comment: I tried that, but still got an error. Please see edit. ThankS1

Comment: @Q-bertsuit a 307 is a redirect, which suggests a config problem; I can't debug a config problem without being able to repro it, but *generally* gRPC *just works*; is what you're doing perhaps available as a github repo that we can *actually run*?

Comment: I created a repo with the issue reproduced. Please see the top of the post. Thanks again!

Comment: I got it working by following this answere https://stackoverflow.com/a/61121433/1235291

Comment: @Q-bertsuit you should answer your post. I overlooked for a long time that this post actually has an answer to my issue because the answer is hidden away in comment. It is not easy to spot that a solution actually has been found