# gRPC service calls in Windows Forms .NET Framework 4.8 client

Tags: asp.net, .net, client, grpc, grpc-web

I am starting with gRPC and maybe anybody can help me with the following issue:

I have a Windows Form in a .NET Framework 4.8 platform and I want to call a service when, for example, I click a button.

To try it, I have create a Server in Visual Studio in ASP.NET Core 3.1, created the .proto file (in a Protos folder) with a simple service and message definition

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "Servidor_gRPC";

service Test {
    rpc Communication(QueryRequest) returns (QueryResponse);
}

message MyRequest {
    string message = 1;
}

message MyResponse {
    string message = 1;
```

then I right-click over the file and set Action = Protbuf compiler and gRPC Stub Classes = Server only.

I build the project and I see Test.cs and TestGrpc.cs classes are created in C:...\Server_gRPC\Server_gRPC\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1 folder.

Now I implement the service in TestService.cs:

```
using Grpc.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Servidor_gRPC
{
    public class TestService : Test.TestBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<TestService> _logger;
        public TestService(ILogger<TestService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public override Task<MyResponse> Communication(MyRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new MyResponse
            {
                Message = "Server received the following client message: " + request.Message
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would create the service in an existing Windows Forms project (in .NET Framework 4.8) by adding the service with a right click mouse button on the client project to get something like:

[image: setting gRPC Service in Cliente]

but I can't add service in this way in my Windows Form project in this .NET Framework platform client. It doesn't give me the option show in the image before, I understand, due to compability:

[image: gRPC compatibility]

I have Windows 10 Pro (in my work), so I can't use WinHttpHandler and, for this reason, gRPC 'basic library' to get services. Then I check gRPC-Web following the [Configure gRPC-Web with the .NET gRPC client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/netstandard?view=aspnetcore-8.0). As it was hard for me to understand all that the link before was explained (and it seems it is more oriented to browsers in web, I can be of course wrong), I followed also this [video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/on-net/grpc-web-with-net) about gRPC-Web with .NET (done by the person who create the gRPC-Web library)

I tried the following:

First, I tried to create a .proto file in the client with the same info set in the server. I create a Fodler 'Protos' and I try to add a Protobufer file, but it was not any existing file option in my Visual Studio 2019. I just made a copy of the .proto file in the server and I changed the namespace for that in the client (WinForm_gRPC):

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "WinForm_gRPC";

service Test {
    rpc Communication(MyRequest) returns (MyResponse);
}

message MyRequest {
    string message = 1;
}

message MyResponse {
    string message = 1;
}
```

Then I build the client project and get the classes expected: Test.cs and TestGrpc.cs were built and placed in C:...\WinForm_gRPC\WinForm_gRPC\obj\Debug\Protos folder.

Now, I install Grpc.NetClient.Web 2.61.0 with NuGet.

With the Test classes generated and the library, I put the next code to make the call to the server:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Uri backendUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:5001");
            var httpHandler = new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWebText, new HttpClientHandler());
            var c = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(backendUrl, new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = httpHandler });            
            var client = new Test.TestClient(c);            

            MyRequest myRequest = new MyRequest();
            myRequest.Message = "Control message";
            
            try
            {
                var response = client.Communication(myRequest);
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }            
        }
```

I build the project and then run it, but in the sentence

var response = client2.Communication(myRequest);

I get the exception:

```
InnerException: "Error sending the request"

Source: "mscorlib"

Message: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. 
HttpRequestException: Error sending the request. 
WebException: The connection has been terminated unexpectedly.",
DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error sending the request.")

StackTrace: en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.<GetResponseHeadersCoreAsync>d__72.MoveNext()
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.HttpClientCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   en Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.<BlockingUnaryCall>b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx)
   en Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation)
   en Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   en WinForm_gRPC.Test.TestClient.Communication(MyRequest request, CallOptions options) en C:\Users\2590\source\repos\WinForm_gRPC\WinForm_gRPC\obj\Debug\Protos\TestGrpc.cs: línea 114
   en WinForm_gRPC.Test.TestClient.Communication(MyRequest request, Metadata headers, Nullable`1 deadline, CancellationToken cancellationToken) en C:\Users\2590\source\repos\WinForm_gRPC\WinForm_gRPC\obj\Debug\Protos\TestGrpc.cs: línea 109
   en WinForm_gRPC.Form1.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) en C:\Users\2590\source\repos\WinForm_gRPC\WinForm_gRPC\Form1.cs: línea 135

TargetSite: {Void ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)}

Trailers: Count = 0, IsReadOnly = true
```

This is the furthest point I could reach.
My questions are:

- Is it possible to use any gRPC service (basic o web) with a Windows Form project in .NET Framework 4.8 platform?
- If it is possible, where did I failed?

I tried this thread: [How do you create a gRPC client in .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766836/how-do-you-create-a-grpc-client-in-net-framework), but it didn't help me (or I didn't know how to integrate that in my issue)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I suppose the problem here is grpc-web requires an intermediary proxy (like envoy) to convert http1 request from the client to http2 to the server and vice versa.

Comment: Yeap @YuriGolobokov, that is what it seems, but it sounds to me strange that I have to install docker in my computer, get the an image of 4-5 Gbytes to install Envoy and that to transform http 2 to htpp 1.1. But I think that is what I have to do, right? Isn't there another 'easier' conversion?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of another options for .NET Framework 4.6.1