# Can i use a .NET Framework gRPC Client against a .net CORE gRPC Server?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, grpc, grpc-dotnet

there is grpc-dotnet, which has more support in Visual Studio for .net CORE
then there is C-Core, which supports old .NET FRAMEWORK versions.

I have an Excel-Addin, which is why i am stuck with .NET FRAMEWORK. Can i program a Server Component in grpc-dotnet and consume that from a .NET FRAMEWORK software?

Comment: They're speaking the same protocol (gRPC), right? So why wouldn't they work? Did you try it out? What was the result?

Comment: I don't see why they should not but if in doubt, I'd create a simple minimal proof of concept.

Comment: I'm trying to make it work but I'm facing a lot of difficulties! Like the Address keep giving me Unavailable Address! Looks like that I need to do something related to SSL but with no hope till now :(

Comment: I got it working. Please try my answer

Comment: My answer got deleted bys moderator as I answered the same at other similar questions.
The idea is I got it working with SSL. Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/63041806/6128864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. gRPC effectively, is an intermediary between two different solutions or projects, just like JSON, which can be used to share data within the same application or across.