# gRPC SSL communication for .NET Framework to .NET Core Server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, protocol-buffers, grpc

Can I use C# Full .NET Framework Client with  C# .NET core client with a secured Channel.?

Can you lead me to some examples where this is done? I could not find anywhere if this can be  done or It Cannot be done.

Detail:
I made an example using .NET Framework client with Grpc C# Github as the reference and .NET Core client with this example from Grpc dotnet as a the reference.
I was able to establish an insecure communication channel with

`new Channel("127.0.0.1", 5000, ChannelCredentials.Insecure)`

and the Non-Https port opened in 5000 in the ASP.NET Core server.

When I try to connect with

`var channel = new Channel("127.0.0.1", 5001, new SslCredentials());`

to the Https port 5000 in the ASP.NET Core ServerI

How can I use a secure channel to communicate. I want to use the same pfx + password combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting this answer for the sake of next person looking for the solution.
I have posted my solution in similar use case question in SO after I got it working [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63041806/6128864) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63041837/6128864)

-- Below is copied from My own answer.

Over SSL or not, you need to turn on Http2 in ASP.NET Core server.  So in appsettings.json, do this.

```
"Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http2"
    }
```

**Insecure .NET Framework Client  +  ASP.NET Core Server**

- ASP.NET Core Server

  1. Remove `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` and `app.UseHsts()` in the `StartUp` class `ConfigureServices(IApplicationBuilder app)`;
  2. Expose the insecure port, typically 80 or 5000 during development.
  3. Use the code below to create insecure channel in .NET Framework client.

```
var channel = new Channel("localhost", 5001, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
```

**Secure SSL connection .NET Framework Client + ASP.NET Core Server**

I got it working with SSL port by using the same Server's certificate in .pem format in the client.

```cs
SslCredentials secureCredentials = new SslCredentials(File.ReadAllText("certificate.pem"));
var channel = new Channel("localhost", 5001, secureCredentials);
```

A bit of explanation. An ASP.NETCore template in VS 2019 uses a development certificate
with pfx file at `%AppData%\ASP.NET\Https\ProjectName.pfx` and
password =  `%AppData%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\{UserSecretsId}\secrets.json {:Kestrel:Certificates:Development:Password} Value`
You can get the `UserSecretsId` id from the `ProjectName.csproj`. This will be different for each ASP.NET Core Project.

I used the below command to convert the pfx + password combination to a `certificate.pem` file.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in "<DiskLocationOfPfx>\ProjectName.pfx" -out "<TargetLocation>\certifcate.pem" -clcerts
```

This will prompt for the pfx password. Use the password from the above `secrets.json`.

Give some passphrase for the `certificate.pem` to be generated(At least 4 letter).

Copy this `cerificate.pem` for the gRPC .NET Framework client to access and use in

```
SslCredentials secureCredentials = new SslCredentials(File.ReadAllText("<DiskLocationTo the Folder>/certificate.pem"))
var channel = new Channel("localhost", 5001, secureCredentials);
```

Note that port 5001 I used is the SSL port of my ASP.NET Core application.

**For Production Scenarios**

Use a valid certificate from certificate signing authority and use same certificate in ASP.NET Core Server and .NET Framework client as `pfx` and `pem` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [my question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62803003/how-can-i-connect-a-grpc-client-in-net-framework-with-a-secure-net-core-server/62825011#62825011). I created a basic sample that may be helpful: https://github.com/angelagyang/GRPCProtobufExample

You can configure a client certificate by creating a **[`KeyCertificatePair`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/csharp/api/Grpc.Core.KeyCertificatePair.html)** to pass into `SslCredentials`. You will need three PEM-encoded strings:

1. PEM-encoded client certificate chain
2. PEM-encoded private key
3. PEM-encoded server SSL certificate.

Here is an example setup:

```
var keyCertPair = new KeyCertificatePair(clientsslcert.pem, privatekey.pem); 
var channelCreds = new SslCredentials(serversslcert.pem, keyCertPair);
```

For testing purposes, I found [these test PEMs helpful](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/core/tsi/test_creds). I used [OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) to convert PFX to PEM format. Additionally, [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/968343/why-do-i-need-a-certificate-to-establish-a-secure-grpc-connection-as-a-client) talks a bit more about the different PEM strings and why the client needs to explicitly trust the server.

Comment: This is a good solution, But I would want to reduce the code to minimum as possible. I got this working without the keyCertPair part, but reading the pem as text.

Please check out my solution.

Comment: Glad to hear it! The KeyCertificatePair only needs to be used if you want to implement client certificate verification (i.e. if the server wants to verify the certificate of the client for an added layer of security).

Comment: I found a way without needing to store the pem on the client side, maybe it's useful for other people as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66041094/727250

Answer (score 0):

I had some luck with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60480334/13156695). Like the OP, I haven't made it work remotely yet. Keep in mind that gRPC isn't supported by IIS yet, so you'll need to find and alternative hosting method too.

Comment: I got it working. Added my solution as answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/63041837/6128864] and here[https://stackoverflow.com/a/63041806/6128864]

Comment: Also, I wouldn't ever want to use IIS if possible.

Comment: Why would you never want to use IIS?  It seems like a perfectly valid reverse proxy, and it provides the additional security and performance benefits of a fully featured web server

Comment: To avoid using windows machine if possible. IIS is windows only. If I could use ASP.NET Core server, I would always go for docker based distributed system with some opensource reverse proxy like nginx than an IIS.